# Add a variable to my struts config result redirection

Tags: struts2, struts-config

I have a page where I'm "Viewing session info" (where session in this context is a business element. Think of a session like a training session). Part of this session info is a list of files. (An example of a session file would be the sign-in sheet of all the people who attended the session.) Clicking the link at the end of the list of files will delete the file from the session via a method called `inativeateSe

In my struts config for `inactivateSessionMaterial`, I have the following result

```
<result name="success">
    /secure/courses/sessions/view_session_info.jsp
</result>
```

But this is insufficient. It really needs to be `view_session_info.jsp?sessionId=1234`. How can I add that variable (session id) to the end of this? Something like

```
<result name="success">
    /secure/courses/sessions/view_session_info.jsp?sessionId=$sessionId
</result>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `<param>` tag inside your action for all results in this action

```
<action>
   <param name="sessionId">${sessionId}</param>
   <result>...</result>
</action>
```

or for specific action result.

```
<action>
   <result>
      <param name="location">...</param>
      <param name="sessionId">${sessionId}</param>
   </result>
</action>
```

Comment: So like `<result name="success">/secure/blah/view.jsp<param name="sessionId">${sessionId}</param></result>` nested inside the result tag?

Comment: Your answer is correct, so I'm accepting it. However, it has led me to an epiphany... I actually want my action to do -nothing-. Is there a way I can do `<result name="success" type="donothing">`?

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by "nothing". You can return `Action.NONE` from your action. See http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/result-configuration.html.